# Self submitting form redirect still contains internal anchor

Tags: coldfusion

I currently have a form which points to itself but more precisely, to an internal anchor for errors:

```
<form action="#errors" method="post">
...
</method>
```

When the form is submitted, I will validate incoming data and if errors are present output them on the screen (located inside the internal anchor). If the data is valid, I will redirect to a confirmation page:

```
<cflocation url="confirm.cfm" addToken="no" />
```

My problem is that the page redirected to still contains the reference to the internal anchor. The URL looks like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/confirm.cfm#errors
```

I've tried this with other languages and was able to replicate this functionality without the anchor remaining after having redirected.

**Edit #1**

This is on CF10, Windows 2008 R2.

Form page:

```
<cfif not structIsEmpty(form)>
    <cfinvoke component="#request.cfcPath#.val" method="init" returnvariable="valObj"></cfinvoke>

    <cfset valObj.validateGame()>

    <cfif valObj.hasErrors()>
        <cfoutput>#valObj.showErrors()#</cfoutput>
    <cfelse>    
        <cfif form.editYN eq 0>
            <cfinclude template="actInsert.cfm">
        <cfelse>
            <cfinclude template="actUpdate.cfm">
        </cfif> 
    </cfif> 
</cfif>
```

actUpdate.cfm

```
<!--- Redirect --->
<cfquery>...</cfquery>
...
<cflocation url="default.cfm?fuseaction=Confirm.gameUpdated" addtoken="No">
```

actInsert.cfm

```
<!--- Redirect --->
<cfquery>...</cfquery>
...
<cflocation url="default.cfm?fuseaction=Confirm.gameAdded" addtoken="No">
```

**Edit #2**

Here's a test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <cfif StructKeyExists(form, "doRedirect")>
            <cfif form.doRedirect eq 1>
                <cflocation url="http://stackoverflow.com" addtoken="false">
            <cfelse>
                <div id="errors">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Some error could have occured here.</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </cfif>
        </cfif>

        <form action="#errors" method="post">
        <div><label for="doRedirect">Do Redirect?</label><select name="doRedirect" id="doRedirect"><option value="0">No</option><option value="1">Yes</option></select></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="Go"/></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you sure it's getting to your `cflocation` code?

Comment: I wonder if confirm.cfm has javascript that tries to go to #errors

Comment: @MattBusche Yeah, as the two pages are unique and the display confirms it.

Comment: I've never had an instance where my page hit a `cflocation` and was adding extraneous data to the url. Can you post code that gives us a repro case?

Comment: @MattBusche see edits for code snippets...

Comment: and what, pray tell, does that fuseaction variable do?

Comment: Why would you put a hash value as the action attribute of a form tag? What is your use case for trying such an action? I understand that you are self posting your form, and I get why (don't personally agree, but it's your app), but I don't understand the purpose there.

Comment: @DanBracuk fuseaction variable is part of the Fusebox framework... version 2 I believe, old codebase :)

Comment: @Steve-Cutter-Blades the hash value, once submitted will redirect to an internal anchor in the page where the errors are to be displayed (vs the user having to scroll there).

Comment: Cflocation is a server-side redirect, occurring within the context of the request. The hash is apparently being included by default of that request. I can't tell you about what other languages are doing, only that this is how CF is interpreting the request context. Knowing that this is an issue, you can a) file a bug report with the product team for unnecessarily passing hash values in redirected requests, and b) find a different solution for your hash use case.

Comment: But, in the case that you've described, your process is actually redirecting to a different page entirely, while retaining the hash in the request. I get the use case now. This comes back to the self posting form. If the processor fuseaction controls the flow, redirecting to the appropriate view, then you can add #errors to your request when required.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a # value in the action part of the form.
Otherwise, you can do like:

```
  <form action="" method="post">
    <div><label for="doRedirect">Do Redirect?</label><select name="doRedirect" id="doRedirect"><option value="0">No</option><option value="1">Yes</option></select></div>
    <div><input type="submit" value="Go"/></div>
    </form>
```